# How to run multiple `socat` and forwarding both TCP and UDP traffic?

Tags: systemd, daemon, socat

I want to forward Microsoft Remote Desktop on a Linux Server, assume that the remote Windows host is `192.168.1.100`, I want to run:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:3389,fork TCP4:192.168.1.100:3389
socat UDP4-LISTEN:3389,fork UDP4:192.168.1.100:3389
```

It works fine when I start the service by hand in the shell, but I want to start it with `systemd`, and log into `/var/log/socat-rdp.log`.

After some trials I can run the service like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Socat RDP Forwarding Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/socat TCP4-LISTEN:3389,fork TCP4:192.168.3.153:3389 > /var/log/socat-rdp.log 2>&1 & /usr/bin/socat UDP4-LISTEN:3389,fork UDP4:192.168.3.153:3389 > /var/log/socat-rdp.log 2>&1 &"
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This configuration starts and runs normally, but when I stop the service with `systemctl stop socat-rdp` it returns error code 1, although `socat` process is killed as normal.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Why not create a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative solution to address the issue of running multiple socat instances and forwarding both TCP and UDP traffic. Instead of using systemd to manage the service, I have utilized Docker to achieve the desired outcome.

I found an Docker image `alpine/socat`, and use Docker Compose to run two `socat` instances for both TCP and UDP at the same time. Here's my Docker Compose file:

```
---
services:
  socat_rdp_tcp:
    image: alpine/socat
    container_name: socat_rdp_tcp
    command: "TCP-LISTEN:3389,fork TCP:192.168.1.100:3389"
    ports:
      - 3389:3389

  socat_rdp_udp:
    image: alpine/socat
    container_name: socat_rdp_udp
    command: "UDP-LISTEN:3389,fork UDP:192.168.1.100:3389"
    ports:
      - 3389:3389/udp
```

Docker image:
[alpine/socat](https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/socat/tags)

Answer (score 0):

when you run socat command directly in terminal and kill them (maybe killall socat ?) the given code is Exit 143?
The easiest dirtyhack is use SuccessExitStatus=143 under [Service].